# Oracle Form hangs frequently

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, threadpool, deadlock

Unable to understand why the form hangs frequently and tried to analyze thread dump. Found no deadlocks. Please help me on this?

I am testing some transactions on Oracle EBS forms with our automation tool (which uses jemmy to automate). While performing actions, form becomes unresponsive. I am using the latest java version (1.8.0.201), IE11 browser.

Sometimes, as soon as the form opens and after one action the form hangs.
Suspected like deadlock was there. So took thread dump and it was showing no deadlock.but many threads are waiting state and runnable state.

For example I am posting two threads stacktraces in this post.
Please suggest how to find the problem and explain me if any learnings.

1)

```
AWT-EventQueue-1 - priority:6 - threadId:0x083b0000 - nativeId:0xd08 - 
nativeId (decimal):3336 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x159e3750> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Locked ownable synchronizers:
   - None
```

2)

```
AWT-EventQueue-1 - priority:6 - threadId:0x083b0000 - nativeId:0xd08 - nativeId (decimal):3336 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x159e3750> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

Comment: If possible, run the form in debug mode in Forms Builder. Set breakpoint into WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger. Set parameters' values in there as well. Navigate through the form step-by-step. Hopefully, you'll find the culprit. However, if you *must* use "jemmy" (whatever that is), no further ideas, sorry.

Comment: What's your products version? ( such as 12.x.x..)

Comment: version is 12.2.4

Answer (score 1):

> It's a kind of **Out Of Memory errors**.

*It seems you need to apply Patch : **21187539** getting through Oracle Support and using **Opatch Utility** for  Version **12.1.0.2.0** and **later***

Comment: If it the problem with memory, how can I confirm that?Is it client side or server side?in client side, I tried in windows task mananger,performance tab is there, where memory left over is visible, so clear that there is memory space.

Comment: @HimaaS I suppose there's a misconfiguration at the server side, maybe related to the load balancing, or non-tested parameter value for the production environment. By the way, are there any other people complaining for such like issues at your corporation?

Comment: As of now,  I only facing this issue in only one machine. In other machines, it is not getting replicated.

Comment: @HimaaS then, you can check the configuration of your local weblogic server, or maybe apply the patch.

Comment: what is this 21187539?

Comment: @HimaaS that's the related patch number could be reached through Oracle Support, so called MOS, https://support.oracle.com .... Most probably your DBA can have the credentials to authenticate.